# Server responded Protocol error packet too long 1349676920

Tags: ssh

What is the solution for above mentioned error. I received that issue while connecting from putty / tectia secure shell tools. I have installed ubuntu server 18.04. Below is the output for ssh and sshd

```
bsaitechnosales@storage:~/.ssh$ sudo netstat -tupln | grep 22
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:9229 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 2473/gitlab-workhor 
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 8843/sshd
tcp6 0 0 :::22 :::* LISTEN 8843/sshd

bsaitechnosales@storage:~/.ssh$ sudo service ssh status
[sudo] password for bsaitechnosales: 
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server 
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) 
Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-12-07 16:06:39 +0545; 27min ago 
Process: 8842 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) 
Main PID: 8843 (sshd) 
Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915) 
CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service 
        └─8843 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Dec 07 16:06:39 storage.bsaitechnosales.com systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server... 
Dec 07 16:06:39 storage.bsaitechnosales.com sshd[8842]: /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 36: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication 
Dec 07 16:06:39 storage.bsaitechnosales.com sshd[8843]: /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 36: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication 
Dec 07 16:06:39 storage.bsaitechnosales.com sshd[8843]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22. 
Dec 07 16:06:39 storage.bsaitechnosales.com sshd[8843]: Server listening on :: port 22. 
Dec 07 16:06:39 storage.bsaitechnosales.com systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server. 
Dec 07 16:22:32 storage.bsaitechnosales.com sshd[10891]: rexec line 36: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication 
Dec 07 16:22:32 storage.bsaitechnosales.com sshd[10891]: Protocol major versions differ for 192.168.0.102 port 51654: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 vs. SSH-1.
```

Comment: Where do you see that error? It isn't in the output you show. Can you connect to the machine?

Comment: While connecting from tectia secure shell tool i received following error https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_YRi8jBSqXPpUKJN_PnPNJAuhEavkzCx/view?usp=sharing

Also While connecting from putty i get following error https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Key_ZjnHK1bcMU70Q17jfccEh5Mu6yyx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I was able to login from putty but could not login from tectia client. Solution was edit  /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and make PasswordAuthentication to Yes